# MySQL Table design for lists and their items

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'd like some guidance in a "best method"-approach for a new table.
I've got a website with several tables. I'm now building a "lists"-section so members can build lists with various items.

For the lists-table I have some general info (title, description, .. very basic)
For the list-items I've got 2 key fields: type and ID. The type determines the table to get the info from and ID is the Primary Key for the record in the given table. And an optional 3rd column "alternative name".

Now, what would be the best approach:

- create a 2nd table "list items" with a foreign key to the list_id, type and item_id
- or would it be better to serialize the 3 columns (type, id, alternative) in text-column "item-data" in the lists-table?

Lists can be of any length although I don't expect many of them to be +100 items.

To clarify: I'v got 3 tables "Authors", "Books", "Magazines". 
The whole idea is that you can create a list with links any record in any of these tables. Eg "Top 10 authors" or "Top 100 Books and Magazines" (or any possible combination).

Comment: [many-to-many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) ?

Comment: can you help on this? Suppose I have a table named hotels with the following coloumns -- type, name. description, menu. Now how do i store the menu????

Comment: What exactly are the list for? Can a member have multiple records on list table (1 to many)? What is a List item? Is it a Table? And if it is how it is related to List table?

Comment: @SwaroopNagendra make your own post with your own question. Kindly don't hijack other's post by asking a separate question in his/her own post.

Comment: I was just asking. I had already posted it. If you wanna answer or help please go here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48035/designing-a-database-for-hotel-menu

Comment: @Edper: a list contains links to data stored in other tables. 1 list can contain x list-elements. To simplify: I've got a table for authors, books and magazines. A list can contain links to any element in any of these 3 tabes (eg 'top 10 authors', but also 'Top 100 Books And Magazines').

Comment: Can mix (for example) authors and books in the _same_ list?

Comment: @Branko: yes. That's why I've got a column TYPE and ID Type refers to either authors, books or magazines. While ID identifies the author, book or magazine.

Comment: So, how by the way you are going to get the Top 100 Books etc, do you use an aggregate function like `COUNT()` or you have separate field for that? Your post honestly is still not so clear to me.

Comment: my apologies Edper, I think that was a bad example: those are user-generated list. A bit like the lists on the imdb (http://www.imdb.com/lists/?ref_=nb_cm_3_nls). But that doesn't matter: my question is if it would be best to save the list-rows in seperate table or to save them in the lists-table as a serialized list in a text-column.